# MySQLI stored procedure return PK/AI insertID

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am using a PHP framework called CodeIgniter for my application. This is using the MySQLI driver for its database work.

This framework has built in support for things like a `query builder` where I could just code the statement into the model, but I am trying to use a `stored procedure` setup.

Anyway, I posted some questions with their support and they suggested asking here would be more appropriate.

In my model, I am calling a stored procedure like so:

```
$data = array("customerID" => 123, "productID" => 456);

...

public function addCustomerToProduct($data){
       $procedure = "CALL addCustomerProduct(?,?)";
       $result = $this->db->query($procedure, $data);
}
```

As it stands, this works perfectly fine. I send an array of data over, I tell my stored procedure to expect two variables, and I pass them along.

**Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addCustomerProduct`(IN in_customerID INT, in_productID INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO order_customer_product (customerID, productID, retailAmountAtPurchase, faceValue)
    SELECT
        in_customerID,
        in_productID,
        p.retail,
        p.faceValue
    FROM
        products as p
    WHERE 
        p.productID = in_productID;   
END
```

While this works fine, I am not able to get the `insert_id` from the PK/AI.

The only way this data is passed back (it seems) is when you use :

```
$this->db->insert('customers', $data);
return $this->db->insert_id();
```

I am trying to stick with stored procedures as it just makes things easier to debug when its all separate.

How can I return the `insert_id` to my application when using a stored procedure setup like this?

Answer (score 1):

Add `OUT the_id` to the argument list.

Just before the `END`, add this statement:  `SELECT INSERT_ID() INTO the_id;`

Then decide how you can retrieve the id from whatever variable you pass into the proc.